# ExactTarget - How would I link back to the GroupDefinition from the CustomerKey given in the AsyncActivityStatus CustomerKey object

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, webservices

I am trying to take a AsyncActivityStatus return object and get the GroupDefinition based on the CustomerKey it returns for a Group Refresh (4 digit number). I've tried looking up by ID, no result. The Group API Object doesn't allow retrieving the CustomerKey but when I look for this Group in the account, this is not the CustomerKey.

Any ideas how I can take the below AsyncActivityStatus object and get back to the resulting GroupDefinition object?

```
(ObjectExtension){
         PartnerKey = None
         ObjectID = None
         Type = "AsyncActivityStatus"
         Properties = 
            (Properties){
               Property[] = 
                  (APIProperty){
                     Name = "Program"
                     Value = "TB Group Refresh 2"
                  },
                  (APIProperty){
                     Name = "StepName"
                     Value = "Step"
                  },
                  (APIProperty){
                     Name = "TaskID"
                     Value = "41932730"
                  },
                  (APIProperty){
                     Name = "ActionType"
                     Value = "Group Refresh"
                  },
                  (APIProperty){
                     Name = "CustomerKey"
                     Value = "8743"
                  },
                  (APIProperty){
                     Name = "StartDate"
                     Value = "3/31/2015 3:30:48 AM"
                  },
                  (APIProperty){
                     Name = "CompletedDate"
                     Value = "3/31/2015 3:32:40 AM"
                  },
                  (APIProperty){
                     Name = "StatusMessage"
                     Value = "GroupDefinition performed AsyncID:  41932730"
                  },
            }
      },
```